# Making a dictionary with multi-indexed values

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following multi-indexed dataframe.

```
Connector Pin Color  Y/N?           
F123      1       R   NaN
          2       O   NaN
          3       Y   NaN
          4      GR   NaN
          5       L   NaN
          6       R   NaN
          7       B   NaN
          8       L   NaN
          9      GR   NaN
          10      O   NaN
C137      1       R   NaN
          2       R   NaN
          3       R   NaN
```

I am trying to make a new dictionary that consists of Connector/Pin and Color. So the value of Index ('F123' , 1) would be equal to R if that makes sense.

```
df1d = dict(zip(df1[index], df1['Color']))
```

Is it possible to set an index as a key with another column being the value? The line above is syntactically wrong but was my thinking when trying to figure this out.

Comment: How many levels does your index have, 2 or 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear whether `Color` is a level of your index. If it is, you can use `reset_index` to elevate your `MultiIndex` to series, then `set_index` and `to_dict`:

```
d = df.reset_index().set_index(['Connector', 'Pin'])['Color'].to_dict()

print(d)

# {('C137', 1): 'R',
#  ('C137', 2): 'R',
#  ...
#  ('F123', 9): 'GR',
#  ('F123', 10): 'O'}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using two `zip`s and `get_level_values`

```
dict(zip(tuple(zip(df.index.get_level_values(0),df.index.get_level_values(1))),df.index.get_level_values(2)))
Out[738]: 
{('C137', 1): 'R',
 ('C137', 2): 'R',
 ('C137', 3): 'R',
 ('F123', 1): 'R',
 ('F123', 2): 'O',
 ('F123', 3): 'Y',
 ('F123', 4): 'GR',
 ('F123', 5): 'L',
 ('F123', 6): 'R',
 ('F123', 7): 'B',
 ('F123', 8): 'L',
 ('F123', 9): 'GR',
 ('F123', 10): 'O'}
```

Or `to_dict` if color is not in index

```
df.Color.to_dict()
Out[740]: 
{('C137', 1): 'R',
 ('C137', 2): 'R',
 ('C137', 3): 'R',
 ('F123', 1): 'R',
 ('F123', 2): 'O',
 ('F123', 3): 'Y',
 ('F123', 4): 'GR',
 ('F123', 5): 'L',
 ('F123', 6): 'R',
 ('F123', 7): 'B',
 ('F123', 8): 'L',
 ('F123', 9): 'GR',
 ('F123', 10): 'O'}
```